# @Cacheable doesn't respect key= in grails?

Tags: caching, grails

I have two controller methods,

```
@CacheEvict(value="showGearListCache")
def edit(Long id) {
}
```

and

```
@Cacheable(value="showGearListCache")
def show(Long id) {
}
```

show caches properly: it doesn't execute twice for any id. However, calling "edit" doesn't uncache that id. So if I call show - edit - show, show will not execute the second time.

I thought that the issue might be that the keys are different, so I tried adding

```
@Cacheable(value="showGearListCache", key="#id")
@CacheEvict(value="showGearListCache", key="#id")
```

to both methods, and noticed that caching stopped working entirely (nevermind evicting). So I inspected what was in the cache by injecting grailsCacheManager into the class, and found out the key it was using was (an example):

```
GET:/[CONTROLLER]/show/83
```

When I would have expected it to have just been "83".

Of course I could just clear all entries every time, but that seems inherently wasteful if I'm only invalidating one.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the key be scoped by the `cache` name?

```
@Cacheable(value="showGearListCache", key="#showGearListCache.id")
@CacheEvict(value="showGearListCache", key="#showGearListCache.id")
```

By default the parameters to a method are considered as keys but accessing them would be from the cache name specifier.

Comment: When I do that, I get:

    Field or property 'id' cannot be found on null

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the current grails cache plugin (v1.1.1) allows evicting a particular key for controller action caches. You can evict with `allEntries=true`.

In `def show(Long id) {}` if you want the key as the `id` then you can specify like `@Cacheable(value="showGearListCache", key="#p0")` where `p0` is the first param in the method.

And the default key generator ([DefaultWebKeyGenerator](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-cache/blob/master/src/java/grails/plugin/cache/web/filter/DefaultWebKeyGenerator.java)) for controller actions uses a combination of request type, URI, and query strings. So your key will be like `GET:/app/controller/show?id=83`.